# how to post scripts to networkmanager's dispatcher.d directory

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, dispatcher

Ubuntu 10.10 64bit athalon, gnome

My basic scenario is I'm connecting to a VPN service (via newtworkmanager pptp protocol) and I'm transferring private data (hence VPN). The service goes down intermittantly and that's alright, probably due to my ISP/OS/VPN. What is not good is that my applications will then continue to transmit data via the eth0 default route and thats not cool. After some looking around I'm suspecting the best way to deal with this is to post scripts into /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d. In short, the networkmanager service will execute scripts in this directory (and pass arguments to the scripts) when anything about the network changes.

My problem is that I can't get any of my scripts to execute. They all have, per the manpage, 0755 permissions and owned by root, but when I change the network state by unplugging ethernet cable, my scripts don't execute. I can execute them from the command line, but not automatically via the dispatcher....

an example script:

```
#!/bin/sh -e


exec /usr/bin/wmctrl -c qBittorrent

exit 0
```

This script is intentionally simple for testing purposes..
I can post whatever else would be helpful.

Comment: You might have better luck on http://askubuntu.com/ or http://serverfault.com/ -- typically the [IPs on the other side of a VPN aren't globally routable](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918), so this is a unique enough situation that packets can be routed there whether or not the VPN is up. Can you add firewalling on the remote end to DROP connections not made via the VPN?

Comment: will look into that, it seems simple though to place scripts locally..

Answer (score 0):

i'm using the syntax `killall -9 any_application_name_here` and that's working just fine. I imagine the script didn't have access to the binary wmctrl.  I think that bash interpreter in this case will only execute bash binaries.

So, in a nutshell, if you want to control your VPN traffic based on network events, one way is to post scripts to `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d` and use binaries that are in bash's default path.